# Java - how to convert unix timestamp from one timezone to another?

Tags: java, timezone, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have unix timestamps stored in UTC and would like to convert them to unix timestamps in the user's timezone.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with this value once you calculate it? Normally you convert a UTC time directly to a String for displaying to the user, converting just the timestamp is not usually very useful.

Comment: Hi @PeterLawrey, basically, I have an AJAX request that expects unix timestamps that are returned in the user's timezone so they can be formatted and do things like "1 hour ago".  The problem is, if the timestamps are stored in UTC and those timestamps are used in the client, then things like "-9 hours ago" might show up.

Comment: how you will get user timezone? do you want to convert at server end or client end?

Comment: I have a tool that converts user IP to timezone on the server.

Comment: @Peter: using GeoIP for this is a bad, bad, *bad* idea. 1. Users often want their timezone settings to remain unaffected when they travel to other countries. 2. Users often use VPN tunnels and proxies. The IP address is irrelevant...

Comment: IP tool may not give accurate results, A better way is send unix timestamp to client and client convert in in secs/milli secs..

Comment: You should always use UTC time for your server and data. Relative times ("one hour ago") are not affected by this, as long as you use UTC consistently. Let the client-end handle user-visible dates...

Comment: @thkala, yep just realized that, sorry for the noise.  As for not using the IP to determine the timezone, what would you recommend instead?  Can javascript get access to the system timezone?

Comment: @Peter: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would use UTC everywhere and only convert the time when displaying to the user. Having backend times in different timezone is likely to lead to confusion you don't need.

If you are dealing with an interface/service which doesn't follow this approach you can do this, you can TimeZone.getOffset(date)

Comment: you are right.  I was not thinking straight and realize I'm already doing all the comparisons using UTC timestamps.  Thanks for confirming my stupidity =)